# How to do xml parsing in Python?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have one ".odf" file.

I only want to separate "Text/Chapter1.xhtml" of href.

How can i do it?

This is sample.

I have one ".odf" file.

I only want to separate "Text/Chapter1.xhtml" of href.

How can i do it?

This is sample.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package version="2.0" unique-identifier="BookId" xmlns="http:/pf">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http:ts/1.1/" xmlns:opf="ht200pf">
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN" id="BookId">urn:19be</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>samplesample</dc:title>
    <dc:creator />
    <dc:language>ko</dc:language>
    <meta name="cover" content="image" />
    <meta content="0.9.18" name="Sigil version" />
    <dc:date opf:event="modification" xmlns:opf="httopf">2019-12-12</dc:date>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item id="tocncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="titlepage" href="Text/titlepage.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter1" href="Text/chapter1.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter2" href="Text/chapter2.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter3" href="Text/chapter3.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter4" href="Text/chapter4.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter5" href="Text/chapter5.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter6" href="Text/chapter6.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
  </manifest>
  <spine toc="tocncx">
    <itemref idref="titlepage"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter1"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter2"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter3"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter4"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter5"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter6"/>
  </spine>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything you want.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils
html='''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package version="2.0" unique-identifier="BookId" xmlns="http:/pf">
  <metadata xmlns:dc="http:ts/1.1/" xmlns:opf="ht200pf">
    <dc:identifier opf:scheme="ISBN" id="BookId">urn:19be</dc:identifier>
    <dc:title>samplesample</dc:title>
    <dc:creator />
    <dc:language>ko</dc:language>
    <meta name="cover" content="image" />
    <meta content="0.9.18" name="Sigil version" />
    <dc:date opf:event="modification" xmlns:opf="httopf">2019-12-12</dc:date>
  </metadata>
  <manifest>
    <item id="tocncx" href="toc.ncx" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="titlepage" href="Text/titlepage.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter1" href="Text/chapter1.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter2" href="Text/chapter2.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter3" href="Text/chapter3.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter4" href="Text/chapter4.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter5" href="Text/chapter5.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
    <item id="chapter6" href="Text/chapter6.xhtml" media-type="application/xhtml+xml"/>
  </manifest>
  <spine toc="tocncx">
    <itemref idref="titlepage"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter1"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter2"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter3"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter4"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter5"/>
    <itemref idref="chapter6"/>
  </spine>
</package>'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
hrefs = doc.manifest.selects('item').select('href()')
print (hrefs)
href = doc.manifest.select("item#chapter1>href()")
print (href)
item = doc.manifest.select("item#chapter1")
print (item)
```

Result:

```
['toc.ncx', 'Text/titlepage.xhtml', 'Text/chapter1.xhtml', 'Text/chapter2.xhtml', 'Text/chapter3.xhtml', 'Text/chapter4.xhtml', 'Text/chapter5.xhtml', 'Text/chapter6.xhtml']
Text/chapter1.xhtml
{'id': 'chapter1', 'href': 'Text/chapter1.xhtml', 'media-type': 'application/xhtml+xml', 'tag': 'item'}
```

Comment: Exactly I want to seperate "Text/chaper1~6.xhtml". I'm sorry to confuse you. Thanks.